# Can a "dataType" instance appear as a sequence diagram lifeline?

Tags: uml

A UML datatype is defined as follows:

> A DataType is a kind of Classifier. DataType differs from Class in that instances of a DataType are identified only by their value. All instances of a DataType with the same value are considered to be equal instances.

Hence we can have an object that is an instance of a data type, but it does not have an identity and is only defined by its attributes.

My question is the following: is it valid to have a lifeline in a UML sequence diagram that represents such an object instantiated from a dataType?

Although I don't see anything against it in the specification, I have never seen it in any example, thus I am curious.

Answer (score 1):

You are right UML metamodel allows Lifeline to represent a Datatype instance as a Class instance for example.

This usually does not make sense because in one hand you have DataType used to represent value with maybe a structure but rarely services/functions and in the other hand you have sequence diagram which aims to represent the sequence of services/functions calls.
That's why you do not often have lifelin typed by Datatype even if it is allowed by UML structure.

Comment: I think it depends on the granularity of the diagram. If you really wanted create a sequence diagram that represent the exact same level as the code then you would use this.